# Select a menu item from Master Page

Tags: c#, select, menu, master-pages, sitemap

I currently have an asp Menu Control which loads a SiteMapDataSource in my Master Page. One of the site map nodes is "Tools" which opens a general "Tools.aspx" content page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
  <siteMapNode url="~/Default.aspx" title="Home"  description="">
    <siteMapNode url="Tools.aspx" title="Tools"  description="" />
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

The "Tools.aspx" page contains an image button that takes the user to another content page "Translator.aspx". When navigating to this page the "Tools" menu item is no longer selected. My question is, how can I select the "Tools" menu item from the master page, within the "Translator.aspx" page?

I have tried the following method within the "Translator.aspx" page load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //check if logged in
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Menu mp_Menu = (Menu)Page.Master.FindControl("mnuMaster");

        foreach (MenuItem mi in mp_Menu.Items)
        {
            if (mi.Text == "Tools")
            {
                mi.Selected = true;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This does not work and it appears that 0 menu items are returned.

Would really appreciate it if someone could shed some light on this issue.

Comment: I think if your Translator "is a tool" you can put it in the tools node..

Comment: I do not want the "Translator" tool to be available as a sub menu however. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

    <siteMapNode title="Tools"  description="">
      <siteMapNode url="Tools.aspx"  title="Tools"  description=""/>
      <siteMapNode url="Translator.aspx" title="Tools"  description=""/>
    </siteMapNode>

Comment: try to add <visible="false"> in the node to hide (Not tested)

Comment: Thanks for your help but visible="false" does not work either. Maybe I need to loop through child items instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by entering the following code in the Master Page:

```
protected void mnuMaster_MenuItemDataBound(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["Translator"] != null)
        {
            if (mnuMaster.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (MenuItem mi in mnuMaster.Items)
                {
                    if (mi.Text == "Tools")
                    {
                        mi.Selected = true;
                        Session["Translator"] = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I then added the following to the "Translator.aspx" page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Session["Translator"] = "true";
        }
    }
```

I don't think this is the ideal solution but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

try moving the code to pre_render or something later in the lifecycle just to make sure that the menus aren't being loaded after load

Comment: I tried putting the method in pre_render so now menus data source loads before the pre_render method. This still did not solve my problem however and still returns 0 count of menu items.